# Heroku deploy java .war file returns Error: spawn java ENOENT

Tags: java, jsp, heroku, servlets, tomcat9

I tried to deploy Java Dynamic Application .war file through a Heroku app by Heroku CLI, both Ubuntu and Windows are returning the name error log:

```
Uploading store.war
events.js:291
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn java ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn java',
  path: 'java',
  spawnargs: [
    '-Dheroku.appName=shielded-waters-44449',
    '-Xmx1g',
    '-Dheroku.warFile=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\store.war',
    '-jar',
    'C:\\Users\\josue\\AppData\\Local\\heroku\\node_modules\\@heroku-cli\\plugin-java\\lib\\heroku-deploy-complete.jar'
  ]
}
```

Found that this error occurs in another applications, but didn't find one where it happens when using deploy command on Heroku CLI. Already tried to the CLI but the problem remains.

Comment: same error for me, And I have an installation script and it was working with the same command one month ago

Comment: @GabrielGarcíaGarrido I think they stopped war support, we can just upload Maven Based Projects.

Comment: It was my error in this case i forgot to set the java home!